# Apache Mod_Rewrite Htaccess for Dynamic URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have this link

www.example.com/1/title

which goes to

www.example.com/post.php?author=1&title=title

because of this rule

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([\w-_:]+)/?$ post.php?author=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Fine, but now how do make it such that if somebody types in www.example.com/post.php?author=1&title=title to redirect to www.example.com/1/title

I have spent literally hours online researching this but the information is vague (at least for me) and not working.

2 things stump me so far:

- Writing the pretty url into dynamic and then dynamic into pretty -
  Doesn't that create a loop?
- I also wanted to go the route of a 301 redirect but I could not find
  any workable code that take variables from the first link to put into
  the redirect. In my head a 301 would be the right choice, but I see a
  lot of people (examples) doing it through RewriteRule.

I understand that (groups) can later be accessed by using $1 and $2... but when trying the reverse I cannot make it work. Eg:

```
RewriteRule ^post.php?author=([0-9]+)&title=([\w-_:]+)$ post/$1/$2
```

But like I said nothing works. I've been beating my head on sites like http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html but I cannot fully understand (or apply) what I'm reading there. Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong or how I should approach this problem?

**Many thanks for any help you can give me**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+post\.php\?author=([^&]*)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ post/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([\w-_:]+)/?$ post.php?author=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you - This almost works. I will see if I can make it fully works. So far it bounces me to http://www.example.com/home/rezz/public_html/post/16/Yoga_to_Combat_Stress_and_Anxiety

Comment: Did a hard path and it worked - RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/post/%1/%2? [R=302,L] - thank you so much.

Comment: Or you can put a slash in target as `RewriteRule ^ /post/%1/%2? [R=302,L]`